# How to edit this Access SQL code

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, database-migration

I am the newbie in this filed so I would appreciate it if you could help me. I have this SQL code in my Access and now I need the same in Microsoft SQL server management studio. So I need to edit something but don't know what and how.

```
SELECT Server.Outlook, Server.Region, 
  Server.Country, Server.Territory, Server.Branch, 
  Server.Tier, Server.Division, Server.Type, 
  Server.Year, Server.sMonth, 
  IIf([Data]="Extra Trips",[Qty],0) AS [Extra Trips], 
  IIf([Data]="Hours",[Qty],0) AS Hours, 
  IIf([Data]="Predict",[Qty],0) AS Predict, 
  IIf([Data]="Reduc",[Qty],0) AS Reduc, 
  IIf([Data]="Rev",[Qty],0) AS Rev, 
  IIf([Data]="Service Req",[Qty],0) AS [Service Req],    
  IIf([Data]="TCUP",[Qty],0) AS TCUP, 
  IIf([Data]="Total Kills",[Qty],0) AS [Total Kills], 
  IIf([Data]="Work Ord",[Qty],0) AS [Work Ord], 
  IIf([Data]="FTE",[Qty],0) AS FTE 
INTO Server_FINAL
FROM Server;
```

Comment: what did you try so far and what does not work? do you have Server and Server_FINAL tables in your SQL Server database?

Answer (score 2):

Your `IIF` statements probably need to be converted to case statements.  For example:

```
CASE WHEN [DATA]='Extra Trips' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END as [Extra Trips],
```

Note: Depending on your particular settings SQL server may use quoted identifiers instead of brackets.  So if it doesn't like `[DATA]` or `[Extra Trips]` try doing `"DATA"` or `"Extra Trips"` instead.